# AVAudioSessionPortHeadsetMic not found on iPad although headset is plugged in

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

```
for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *inputPort in inputs) {            
        
        if ([inputPort.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadsetMic]){
            NSLog(@"HeadsetMic Found");
            break;
        }
}
```

Headset Mic not found on iPad, but is found on iPhones. Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: can you log the `inputPort`s that you do see?

Comment: It's found on the iPads I tried. Have you 1. set a recording category, 2. activate the audio session and 3. attached a headset with mic, using an adaptor when no jack is available?